# php time() vs mktime() for current timestamp

Tags: php, time, mktime

Are there any differences between using functions **time()** and **mktime()** with default parameters to obtain current timestamp?

Comment: `time()` is timezone independent while `mktime()` is not

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"As of PHP 5.1, when called with no arguments, mktime() throws an E_STRICT notice: use the time() function instead."

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

If you want to use dates/times, I recommend DateTime instead.

Comment: This is driving me a little crazy. What is the reasoning behind showing this warning? Why is it wrong to call `mktime()` with no parameters? Why have two separate functions at all? Is there any *real* difference between calling `time()` and calling `mktime()` with no parameters?

Comment: If you would like to get the **current** Unix timestamp use `time()`. If you would like to get the Unix timestamp for a **specific** date/time, then you should use `mktime()`. There may be cases you want to work with a Unix timestamp instead of a formatted Date/Time string.  In addition to the DateTime recommendation made by @Anyone, I would like to recommend you use Carbon. Carbon is an extension of DateTime that makes it easier to work with dates and times.

Comment: And as of PHP 8.0, calling with no arguments isn't an option at all - it will throw an error.